# Understanding expansion in tblr environment

Tags: expansion, token-lists, tblr

I'm trying to understand how tokens and expansion work in the context of the following problem. I'd like to create a `tblr` environment from the `tabularray` package via a command that does some of the formatting programmatically. Unfortunately, the `tblr` environment does not like this. A minimal working example is shown below. If I manually shade cells (1, 2) and (1, 3) orange, there are no problems:

```
\documentclass{article}

% Packages
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% Commands
\newcommand{\someRow}{1}
\newcommand{\someColumns}{2, 3}
\newcommand{\someColour}{orange}
\newcommand{\someTable}{%
    \begin{tblr}{
        colspec = {ccc},
%        cell{\someRow}{\someColumns} = {\someColour},
        cell{1}{2,3} = {orange!20},
    }
        a & b & c \\
        d & e & f \\
        g & h & i
    \end{tblr}
}

% Document
\begin{document}
    \someTable
\end{document}
```

[image: Table appears with correct cells shaded orange]

But if I want the values `2, 3` and `orange!20` to appear as results of calling functions `\someColumns` and `\someColour` respectively (i.e. if I uncomment line 15 and comment out line 16), I get a bunch of errors, starting with:

```
./main.tex:26: Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again> 
                   ,
l.26     \someTable
```

If anyone can help me fix this, and explain a little bit about what's going on here, I'd be very grateful!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

You can expand the arguments before passing to `tblr`

```
\documentclass{article}

% Packages
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% Commands
\newcommand{\someRow}{1}
\newcommand{\someColumns}{2, 3}
\newcommand{\someColour}{orange}
\newcommand{\someTable}{%
\ExpandArgs{ne}
\begin{tblr}{
        colspec = {ccc},
        cell{\someRow}{\someColumns} = {\someColour},
%        cell{1}{2,3} = {orange!20},
    }
        a & b & c \\
        d & e & f \\
        g & h & i
    \end{tblr}
}

% Document
\begin{document}
    \someTable
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice! Where is `\ExpandArgs` documented?

Comment: Found it! It is documented in section 4 of [LaTeX for authors](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/usrguide.pdf). Still, its use here might require some explanation ...

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly. Much like @JasperHabicht above I would also love an explanation of why this works - in particular I can't see a reference for the spec `ne` after `\ExpandArgs` in the documentation linked above.

Comment: @Yossarian `e` is covered by the final line of the `ExpandArgs` description: There are several other single letters supported in the L3 programming layer
that could be used in the ⟨spec⟩ to manipulate arguments in other ways. If
you are interested, take a look at the “Argument expansion” section in the L3
programming layer documentation in interface3.pdf

Comment: Ah cool, thanks!